# Как использовать gpio в Raspberry pi через Website?

Tags: php, raspbian, gpio

Как в php (Apache) наладить отношения(чтение и запись) с GPIO, минуя проблемы с правами?

Comment: Почитайте [Веб-контроль Raspberry Pi GPIO](http://habrahabr.ru/post/162651/) и вот например [php библиотека для работы с GPIO](https://github.com/ronanguilloux/php-gpio)

Comment: Это я читал. Мне надо через puthon

Comment: почему тогда тег стоит php?

Comment: Надо создать puthon демона для работы с GPIO, которым будет управлять PHP.